# Media Query responding at a different pixel mark than designated

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query for a navbar element set at 767px, but the changes are triggered at 575-576px.

The media query changes designated at 1023px (h1 element), are triggered at 767px as well.

Please advise on why this happens and how to remedy.
I am using a style.css file, and a queries.css file.  These are the only two css in my project.

html:

```
<body>
 <div class = "nav-wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="resources/css/images/HackAgeLogo1.png" alt="hackage-logo">
        <a href="#"> Aging as Disease </a>
        <a href="/Senescence/senescense.html"> Cellular Senescence </a>
        <a href="/companies/companies.html"> Companies </a>
        <a href="#"> Clinical Trials </a>
        <a href="#"> Reading List </a>
        <a href="npi/npi.html"> Supplements & NPI </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

style.css code:

```
.navbar a:link,
.navbar a:visited {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 18%;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #000;
  margin: 2%;
  transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -o-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
}
.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
}
```

queries.css code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar a:link,
  .navbar a:visited {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    margin: 1%;
  }
  .navbar a:hover,
  .navbar a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
  }

  .subtitle {
    font-size: 60%;
  }

  .main-headline a {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I have now realized that my h1 element is also not responding at the designated pixel mark.  On my browser, the changes designated at 1023px actually happens at 767px...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this in a codepen and the changes happen exactly at 767px. It would helpful if you could provide the corresponding html as well, so we can reproduce the error more clearly.

Comment: I've added the relevant html and additional media queries that aren't acting right.

Comment: It worked for me on codepen as well, but not on my editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have update your queries.css, the `closing braces` are `not closed perfectly`. Also check other `media queries` perfectly closed or not.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar a:link,
  .navbar a:visited {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    margin: 1%;
  }
  .navbar a:hover,
  .navbar a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
  }
} //End here

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 250%;
  }

  .subtitle {
    font-size: 60%;
  }

  .main-headline a {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
} //End here
```

Comment: I used the other version provided, no change in pixel trigger.  Instructions meant for 1023px are happening at 767px, and instructions at 767px are actually happening at 575px

Comment: checkout your closing brackets, if you found the solution then please vote, Thank you @kio777kio

Comment: I actually found the root of this issue to be with browser compatibility.  I was working on BRAVE browser, and the media queries were nit responding correctly.  When I tried with Chrome, they worked fine.  So I've switched back to Chrome. I never figured out the actual problem with BRAVE.